# TCP Client Class implementation in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, .net

I tried to implement following class which should handle connecting to a server, as well as sending and receiving data.

Your feedback is welcome. Please note I am beginner in .NET and don't give too advanced feedback. I tested it and it seems to work. So in case you see some major problems please let me know, otherwise this class seems to fulfill my needs. I may add some small functionalities though.

Also can I better release resources than I am doing now? (maybe automatically close all resources I am using if that's possible?)

```
 class DppTCPClient
    {
        public TcpClient m_client = new TcpClient();

        public void Connect(string address, int port)
        {
            if (m_client.Connected)
                throw new Exception("Connect: Already connected");

            m_client.Connect(address, port);
        }

        public void WriteBytes(byte[] data, int length)
        {
            if (data.Length != length)
                throw new Exception("WriteBytes: Length should be same");

            // Get access to network stream
            Stream stm = m_client.GetStream();
            stm.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        }

        public void ReadAllBytes(byte[] buffer, int length)
        {
            if (buffer.Length != length)
                throw new Exception("ReadAllBytes: Length should be same");

            Stream stm = m_client.GetStream();

            // Start reading
            int offset = 0;
            int remaining = length;
            while (remaining > 0)
            {
                int read = stm.Read(buffer, offset, remaining);
                if (read <= 0)
                    throw new EndOfStreamException
                        (String.Format("ReadAllBytes: End of stream reached with {0} bytes left to read", remaining));
                remaining -= read;
                offset += read;
            }

        }

        public void CloseDppClient()
        {
            if (m_client.Connected)
            {
                m_client.GetStream().Close();
                m_client.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For `ReadAllBytes`: Why do I need to provide the length if you can get it yourself?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Maybe you wana read fewer bytes then length of byte array(but now it doesn't work like that)

Answer (score 18):

It looks like you should be implementing [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) here. [See on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then, in your `Dispose(bool)` method, you can call `CloseDppClient` (or, better yet, do them the other way around and call `Dispose()` from your `CloseDppClient` method).

You should also be putting explicit access modifiers on your classes, properties, methods, fields, events, etc. As it stands now, `DppTCPClient` is internal.

Also, it's usually expected to follow `PascalCasing` throughout C# programs for `public`, `class`, `interface` and `enum` definitions.

I've left `DppTcpClient` as `internal`, but if you want it accessible outside the assembly simply replace `internal` with `public`.

An example would look like:

```
internal class DppTcpClient
    : IDisposable
{
    // Flag: Has Dispose already been called?
    bool disposed = false;

    // Original code

    public void CloseDppClient()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);           
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
        {
            return; 
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (m_client.Connected)
            {
                m_client.GetStream().Close();
                m_client.Close();
            }
            // Free any other managed objects here.
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here.
        disposed = true;
    }

    ~DppTcpClient()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Then, you should be `using` your `DppTcpClient` where you need it:

```
using (DppTcpClient client = new DppTcpClient())
{
    // Code to use `client` here
}
```

So long as you always wrap any `DppTcpClient` objects with a `using`, you'll never run into a stale client left open.

---

Always use braces.

> ```
> if (data.Length != length)
>     throw new Exception("WriteBytes: Length should be same");
> ```

Should be written as:

```
if (data.Length != length)
{
    throw new Exception("WriteBytes: Length should be same");
}
```

Braces can't prevent bugs, but they can help prevent bugs. (If you know what I mean.)

---

From what I can tell, your `ReadAllBytes` method is actually not supposed to read all the bytes in the stream (or so it sounds), by this manner you should be changing how you work with it internally.

Instead of having the user supply a buffer, *you* should supply it by use of either:

1. A `return` type;
2. An `out` parameter;

The `return` type would be more appropriate here, so you could do something like:

```
public byte[] ReadAllBytes()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        m_client.GetStream().CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387979/get-length-of-data-available-in-networkstream for more information on reading the entire stream.

This simplifies it greatly, and takes a large brunt of the work off your shoulders.

Just as well, you can completely remove the `int length` parameter from the `WriteBytes` method:

> ```
> public void WriteBytes(byte[] data, int length)
> {
>     // Get access to network stream
>     Stream stm = m_client.GetStream();
>     stm.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
> }
> ```

Lastly, I would rename your `ReadAllBytes` method to `ReadBytes`, since that's what it's doing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30221/discussion-on-answer-by-ebrown-tcp-client-class-implementation-in-c).

Comment: MemoryStream can also take existing array in constructor, if you chose to reuse arrays. However, you changed semantics. Original ReadAllBytes throws an exception if connection cannot provide expected amount of bytes.

Answer (score 10):

Seems pretty solid, but there are some style things that I would personally change.

In

```
public void WriteBytes(byte[] data, int length) { ... }
```

and

```
public void ReadAllBytes(byte[] buffer, int length) { ... }
```

there doesn't seem to be a need for the length parameter. This would get rid of the data.Length and buffer.Length checks and related exceptions.

In Connect, WriteBytes, and ReadAllBytes, ensure that all of the parameters are 'trusted'; meaning you know exactly where they come from and that they are safe and not null.

Style wise, it is helpful to make comments above each of these methods stating that each method is expecting good/safe parameters.

The ReadAllBytes method, may be simplified:

```
/// <summary>
/// TODO
/// </summary>
/// <param name="buffer">The buffer to read data from. Assumed to be not null.</param>
public void ReadAllBytes(byte[] buffer)
{
    Stream stm = m_client.GetStream();
    while (stm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

No need to over-complicate things by tracking variables that have no use. If you do have a use for say the offset variable in the future, add it then, not now. Right now, there is no use; keep it simple.

Comment: I've never seen these comments you're talking about assuming the safety of the class. Plus, written this way they're not even visible in the IDE. Otherwise, good answer!

Comment: Maybe this isn't the place, but is there a 'good' way to handle possible null values? Or is it better to take the defensive approach and always assume the worse (ie, check that buffer != null in this case)?

In addition, what about try/catching blocks of code. Like if we assume that this is suppose to throw exceptions that are passed up to the caller? Is that just a comment in that case?

Comment: There's a `[NotNull]` attribute you can use, that indicates value shouldn't be null but doesn't make any validation. Apart from that, always be defensive about your input, you don't know if the user of your class is Satan or Bugs Bunny (who will be considered kind for this example). With the method's xml header there's a way to specify thrown exceptions! Check it out :)

Comment: @TopinFrassi isn't [NotNull] part of the ReSharper annotations framework? AFAICT it only tells R# to check the call site isn't passing a possibly null reference.

Comment: [Seem's it's not only resharper!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896853/notnull-attribute)

Answer (score 6):

My biggest issue with your code is that it doesn't achieve anything useful. It's pretty much a thin wrapper over `TcpClient` that doesn't add any abstraction or features.

Btw your `ReadAllBytes` function exists in the BCL, in the form of `BinaryReader.ReadBytes`. If you want to use it without having to instantiate `BinaryReader` (which  prevents you from using the underlying stream) I'd rather add a `ReadBytes` extension method to `Stream` instead of adding it on your TcpClient wrapper.

Passing in `byte[]` arrays as buffer is idiomatic in IO code and avoids unnecessary allocations. So choosing between returning a new instance `byte[]` and writing into an existing `byte[]` is a performance-simplicity trade-off. In my experience using existing buffers is preferable in low level code, since you don't know how it will be used and returning new instances is preferable if you write high level code and know that you don't need much throughput. As a variant of passing in buffers, you can pass in an `ArraySegment<byte>`.

---

Concerning the disposing: Since you don't own any unmanaged resources directly, all you need to do is forward your `Dispose` call to the disposable type you're wrapping. Optionally make it `virtual` if you want derived classes to be able to add ownership of additional disposable types.

Something like:

```
class DppTCPClient : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        m_client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your comments to Ebrowns answer! I was trying to explain to him similar points as you did, bot no result! Finally, can you please show me how to handle deallocating resources in the best way? As Ebrowns answer's approach was flawed as you indicated. If I leave it as I have now, what if exception happens, when should I call CloseDppClient  on my class?

Comment: @quser The point was that when a method alters a parameter,  best-practice is to use `ref` or `out` to indicate as such, otherwise your method has surprising/unexpected side effects that need to be documented - and because self-documenting code is superior to surprising but documented code, using `out` or `ref` is preferred *in this particular case*. Generally speaking, returning a value is preferred to using `ref` or `out` parameters.

Comment: @Mat'sMug You should only use `out`/`ref` if you replace the whole instance, not if you just mutate the contents of a mutable type. In general I'd consider `out` only a work-around for .net's lack of support for multiple return values.

Comment: About disposing: Is that what you added all? And then I should use my class object with using statement? PS. I read somewhere disposing tcp client doesn't dispose stream, is it right?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I agree, array is reference type so I can also modify like that. Anyway, that is not big issue I am interested more in disposing parts; there were other weak points in Ebrowns answer also

Comment: @CodesInChaos: How and where do I call this Dispose (of my class)??

Comment: "I read somewhere disposing tcp client doesn't dispose stream, is it right?" the shutdown seems to be somewhat differently if you dispose the stream instead of the client, I'll need to investigate the details. It might have something to do with waiting until data has been sent and acknowledged by the receiver or not waiting.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I will appreciate if you help with this matter. Please let me know how to do this properly. Many thanks in advance. It seems the other answer is not correct in disposing? Please also show me how to use it then

Comment: @quser `using` as in EBrown's answer is fine. His answer approach isn't incorrect just over-complicated.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: So what shall I do? Shall I implement using as in his answer (the whole code snippet he showed related to automatic disposing)? Or wait till you find out how to do it? PS. don't worry about functionality, I will need probably to add some more functionality to this class but need to know that my basics is right

Comment: @quser do note that reviewers don't even have to include code in their answers, those who do, do it as a courtesy. Feel free to ask on Stack Overflow if you need help with a specific issue; this is drifting from the scope of Code Review.